# how to reload or refresh an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

in my array i stored database value and delete by user that time i want to reload the array.how to refresh the array?.i also reload table but i not helful for me i want at a time effect on table.

**i tiered to use this:**

```
[tableview begineUpdate];
[tableview reloadrowatindexpath:withanimation:];
[tableview deleterowatindexpath:withanimation:];
[tableview endupdate];
```

**for array i alse used this:**

```
array = [NSMutablearray new];
```

Comment: [you just reload your array see this post :](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424957/how-to-delete-rowatindexpath-without-swipe-from-custome-delete-button-graphic)

Comment: @seggy thank you buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before reload the table you just `removearrayatindexpath`

or recall ur array befor reloading the table

```
//if u are not using in `tableview` method
[tableview begineUpdate];
//here you call ur array again
[tableview reloadrowatindexpath:withanimation:];
[tableview endupdate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Before reload table remove entry from array.

[yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: thanx buddy @shuvo

Comment: Great! Hope it helps you. You can accept my answer if it's helping you. :-p